# Highlight textview inside RecyclerView list

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclick, textview

I am using a recycler view to show a list and it contains an id and value mainly. Now when I click on the item in a list only the value should become bold or highlighted and again if I select any other item the previously highlighted item should become normal and the selected item should become bold.

I am able to highlight the value (Basically it's a text view). But the problem is if I select any other item it's not removing the previously selected item boldness.

Following is a piece of code where on click of item value it ll bold the value

```
final ReturnPackageModel model = PackagesList.get(position);
...........................................................
...........................................................

holder.packageId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mTextClickListener.onTextClick(view,position,PackagesList);
            holder.packageId.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            model.setTapped(true);
        }
    });
```

onTextClick is a callback function which am using in my activity.

Any help would be appreciated ThankYou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the tapped states of other items in list as `false` as soon as you tap one of them.

```
holder.packageId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mTextClickListener.onTextClick(view,position,PackagesList);
            holder.packageId.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            model.setTapped(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < MyList.size(); i++) {
                ReturnPackageModel model1= PackagesList.get(i);
                if(position != i){
                    model.setTapped(false);
                    notifyDatasetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank You for solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use your data model to track selection index by putting a boolean field **isSelect** in your model and a integer field **lastSelected** in adapter

```
 when click at i
      list(i).setIsSelect(true)
      list(lastSelected).setIsSelect(false)
      notifyItemChangedAt(i)
      notifyItemChangedAt(lastSelected)
      lastSelected = i
```

now use s=isSelect field in bind view method to highlight text

Comment: Thanks for your time